# Can Android Studio Method Tracer tool tracing appliction cold lanuch process?

Tags: android, monitor, trace

I want to profiling launch performance for my application, but when I want to tracing the cold lanuch process, but i see that[image]

start tracing button can not clickalbe and monitor is disabled.

When I open my application, it's too late to click start tracing button, any one can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can set breakpoint at Appliction onCreate() or Main Activity onCreate()
in debug mode. When execute at breakpoint, click the start tracing button. It's work.